# Colorbar sticking to axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a small problem with the positioning of a colorbar using matplotlib. I'm plotting several subplots and one of them is an image. I want this image to have a colorbar but I want it to be "stuck" to the figure, so that there is no space between the two axes (the one from the figure and the one from the colorbar). Even if the figure is resized, the colorbar should always stick to the image axes.

PS - I don't mind if ax3 (the axes of my image) is deformed.

Here's what I've got for the moment:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from scipy import *

# Generating data
data = (rand(2048,2048), rand(2048,2048)+1000)
colorplot = "blue"
metadata = ("Test1", "Test2", "spectral")

# Generating figure and subplots
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(right = 0.8)

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 5)
gs1.update(left=0.05,\
           right=0.95,\
           top=0.95,\
           bottom=0.05,\
           wspace=0.2,\
           hspace=0.05)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1:3,0:2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:,2:])

list_axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]     

for i in list_axes:
    i.autoscale_view(tight=False, scalex=False, scaley=True)

# Misc computation
array = data[1]-data[0]
mean_value = np.mean(array)
std_value = np.std(array)
nb_sigma = 5

ax1.imshow(data[0], interpolation = "nearest", cmap = metadata[2])
ax2.imshow(data[1], interpolation = "nearest", cmap = metadata[2])

im = ax3.imshow(array, vmin = np.min(array[array>mean_value-nb_sigma*std_value]), vmax = np.max(array[array<mean_value+nb_sigma*std_value]), interpolation = "nearest", cmap = metadata[2])

ax3.set_adjustable('box-forced')
# Creating axes for the colorbar
axes_cb = fig.add_axes([ax3.get_position().bounds[0],ax3.get_position().bounds[1], ax3.get_position().bounds[2], 0.05])
fig.colorbar(im, cax = axes_cb, orientation = 'horizontal')
axes_cb.yaxis.tick_left()

n, bins, patches = ax4.hist(array.flatten(), color = colorplot, bins = 50, normed = True)

plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not able to get all the way there (at least not yet), but I have had some progress with  "cax, kw = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax3, pad = 0.0)" [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid2.html)